# How does call method without the variable assign in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++builder

I'm trying to understand code below.

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;

class A
{
  public :
    void Test();
};

void A::Test()
{
   ShowMessage("Hello");
}

__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
 A *x;
 x->Test();
}
```

I expect EAccessViolation error,when I call the Test method.

How does work without the x assign ?

Comment: It's undefined behaviour, anything can happen including the behaviour you see.

Answer (score 4):

> How does work without the x assign ?

In theory, the posted code is cause for undefined behavior.

In practice, it works some times because `A::Test()` does not depend on any member data. It is not guaranteed to work in every platform.

Comment: Which platform does not work properly ? I want test it.

Comment: @İsmailKocacan nobody can tell you. It might work under some external circumstances on one platform like e.g. compiler switches. As R Sahu wrote: it is _undefined_ behaviour, so the compiler is free to take the phase of the moon to decide what to do here.

Comment: @İsmailKocacan, I tested your code with VS 2008, VS 2010, and g++ 4.9.3 under cygwin. All of them worked fine. But then, that doesn't tell where it could fail. That's the hard part of **Undefined Behavior**. You don't know when you are going to be hit by a problem.